# how long does it take for food to convert to fat?

Tags: food, body-fat

If I ate two pounds of food and then was immediately there after subjected to a hydrostatic body fat my suspicion is that that food would not count as body fat since it wouldn't have had the chance to convert to body fat yet.

Assuming that that's correct than how long would it take for it to turn into fat? A day? Two days? A few hours?

Comment: Sorry, but because this is not a fitness question, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Check this out:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be what you're looking for but don't worry about stuff like this. First of all, there is no determined amount of time that food will automatically turn into fat.

Instead of thinking in these terms, just feed your body proper nutrition, stay active, continue to exercise and your body will use this food as fuel. In the end it's "Calories In vs Calories Out" for weight loss/gain, so combine that with a good diet and you don't have to worry about silly details like how long until it turns to fat.

Comment: The main reason I ask is because I'm participating in a weight loss contest where the winner is the person who lost the most percent body fat. Maybe it's cheating to artificially inflate my weight (but not my body fat) by eating right before but ethics aside I'm still curious.

Comment: dont you have to be sober for those contests (sober as in no eating, no drinking). Otherwise, why not drink 5l of water?